# How can I execute a git extension pull form many repository

Tags: git, repository, pull, git-extensions

How can I execute a git pull form many repositories?
It's possible using GitExtension?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean to fetch from every branch the command is

```
git fetch --all
```

Other than there there is no auto merging strategy for such a pull.